# Type casting anonymous type to IEnumerable type

Tags: vb.net

Code:

```
Dim query As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = From row In datatable.AsEnumerable() _
                        Select New With {
                       .messageId = row.Field(Of Integer)("Message_Id"), _
                       .severity = row.Field(Of String)("Severity")}

Dim dt As DataTable = query.CopyToDataTable
```

I am taking a few columns from a `DataTable` and copying into a new `DataTable`. But it gives me the following error:

> System.Data.EnumerableRowcollection (of anonymous type) cannot be
>   converted System.collections.Generic.IEnumerable (of
>   System.data.datarow).

How do I proceed?

Comment: Why are you creating an anon type rather than filtering the datatable or selecting DataRows from it

Comment: #Plutonix as I have where clause to be added so I did this

Comment: The source and destination datatables must have same structure.  So if 2nd datatable is not same structure create a new datatable with correct structure for output.

Comment: second datatable is a new one and doesnt has structure it just takes the  copy of selected columns from linq query

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new type here:

```
Select New With {
.messageId = row.Field(Of Integer)("Message_Id"),
.severity = row.Field(Of String)("Severity")
}
```

And trying to cast that new type into a `DataRow`. That's why you are getting the error.

You can you use the following code to filter your data:

```
 Dim query = From row As DataRow In dtTable.Rows
                        Where row("colunm_name").ToString = "condition"
                        Select row
```

This will give you `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)`.